# react redux-beacon track link clicks analytics

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-redux, react-router, redux-beacon

What's the best way to track internal link clicks analytics in a React/Redux App if using Redux-Beacon?

Normally a internal link click fires a router location change (it doesn't fire any other redux action). But 'LOCATION_CHANGE' it is actually a *pageView*.

Is it ok, to dispatch an event before the `history.push('...')`? Like:

```
dispatch({ type: VIEW_BLOG_POST, postId });
.....
history.push(`/${postId}`);
...
```

Without really changing the state, but just to catch the event with redux-beacon middleware?

...
Also what about external link clicks? Do I need to manage these different? (I want to avoid mixed tracking implementations)

Comment: Looks like Redux-Beacon only maps ga events to redux states. So as long as route change isn't a change in Redux state you'll need a separate GA integration.

Comment: Not quite @ДмитроБулах. Redux Beacon maps Redux or Ngrx actions to GA events (when using the GA target). Redux Beacon doesn't care if the state changes or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok, to dispatch an event before the history.push('...')?

Yes, that is perfectly okay. All you have to do is map `VIEW_BLOG_POST` to a new event definition. The action does not have to change the state in any way. It will pass through the reducers which will all return a reference to the previous state. If you're using react-redux this will have a near-zero impact on performance. Assuming you're tracking this as an event in GA it would look something like this:

```
import { trackEvent } from '@redux-beacon/google-analytics';

const trackBlogPostClick = trackEvent((action, prevState, nextState) => {
  return {
    category: /* fill me in */,
    action: /* fill me in */,
    label: /* (optional) */,
    value: /* (optional) */,
  };
}, /* (optional) tracker names array or tracker name string */ );

// And wherever your events map is:

const eventsMap = {
  VIEW_BLOG_POST: trackBlogPostClick,
}
```

> Without really changing the state, but just to catch the event with redux-beacon middleware?

> Also what about external link clicks? Do I need to manage these different? (I want to avoid mixed tracking implementations)

This largely depends on how you want to track these in Google Analytics. But there is nothing wrong with treating them the same way from redux-beacon's standpoint.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer and help! 